# Can't connect to SQL Server 2005 unless using 127.0.0.1

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm not able to connect to sql server with anything but 127.0.0.1 on the server machine. If I try to connect via actual IP on the network it does not work locally or remotely.

The environment is SQL Server 2005 on Windows Server 2000. My goal is to connect to this SQL Server instance from a remote machine.

I've tried telneting to port 1433 using the actual IP and that fails. I've tried turning off Windows Firewall completely

Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable remote connections - check this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277)

Comment: Remote connections was already enabled and I still have this problem.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the firewall settings. You need to create exceptions to allow remote connections in the firewall